# PayPal sandbox issue (redirected to 'My Account')

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have two PayPal Sandbox/Developer accounts - 1 is mine, 1 is my clients.

I have build a form for donations, we have had this working for a while and testing has always been done against my personal dev account. Its always been fine, no problems.

Recently we needed to make some changes and we thought it would be beneficial for the client to get their own account to make it easy for them to see everything working properly.

Changing the Sandbox address to any one of the merchant addresses that I have created using their sandbox account has the strangest issue - when clicking my 'Donate' button, I am redirected to the 'My Account' screen for that feaux-merchant account. I am not taken to the donation summary or a confirmation, I get no option to pay, I just get taken to the same screen that you would get when logging in to paypal to view your account.

If I switch the email address back to my personal fake merchant, no problems.

I can see no differences between the merchant accounts.

Hopefully one of you PayPal geniuses can shed some light on this.

**EDIT/Clarification:**

There has been some misunderstanding, so to clarify;

I have **two** developer accounts
Each has a merchant & seller account
I **am** logged in to the correct developer account before testing
I am **not** being redirected to the login page - I am being redirected to the My Account summary.

Comment: I'm not a Paypal genius but make sure your client has a sandbox account if he want to get paid for that account in sandbox site (main Paypal accounts dot work in sandbox).

Comment: Hi Ayesh, as stated, we have two sandbox accounts.

Comment: Both sandbox account should have created using same developer account and you should be logged in using dev. account before testing.

Comment: I am getting this same issue.  

Have you solved it??

Answer (score 0):

When using paypal sandbox account for testing, you should be logged in using your **developer account.** Merchant addresses and client addresses (test logins in sandbox) both created using this developer account will only redirect you to donation summary and pay options. 
If you use other Merchant addresses which are not created using your developer account will redirect you to login page of paypal.

Comment: I have updated the question to confirm that this is what I have been doing. Thanks.